# Spring Boot, filling two equal component-classes from different properties-files

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a problem with a spring boot application.
The application uses saml for communication with an other server. Therefor I have a class with component annotation to read some properties from a custom properties file (not from application.properties) for communication information like url. 
I'm not allowed to post the real code, so this is an example in pseudocode.

```
@Component
public class A implements ConfigInterface {

@Value ("${placeholder1 from properties-File}")
private ... value1;
@Value ("${placeholder2 from properties-File}")
private ... value2;

...
}
```

The controller for usage looks like:

```
@Controller
public class controller {
@Autowired
private ConfigInterface config;

public method ( ... ) {
    ...
    createAMessage(config);
    ...
}
}
```

My Task is to copy the class A into a class B and load similar properties from a different properties-file.
Here an example again:

```
@Component ("classAProperties")
public class A implements ConfigInterface {

@Value ("${placeholder1 from properties-File1}")
private ... value1;
@Value ("${placeholder2 from properties-File1}")
private ... value2;

...
}



@Component ("classBProperties")
public class B implements ConfigInterface {

@Value ("${placeholder1 from properties-File2}")
private ... value1;
@Value ("${placeholder2 from properties-File2}")
private ... value2;

...
}
```

Usage:

```
@Controller
public class controller {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("classAProperties")
private ConfigInterface configA;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("classBProperties")
private ConfigInterface configA;

public methodA ( ... ) {
    ...
    createAMessage(configA);
    ...
}

public methodB ( ... ) {
    ...
    createAMessage(configB);
    ...
}
}
```

The problem is, how do I can tell class A to load the properties only from properties-file1 and class B only from properties-file2? I've tried to use @PropertiesSource-annotation in both classes A and B but at the end it always uses the properties from class B in both methods of the controller.

Edit:

Both Properties-files are in resources-folder.
The properties-files look like:

```
propertiesA.properties
placeholder1 = URL for destination
placeholder2 = Path to keystore
...

propertiesB.properties
placeholder1 = URL for other destination
placeholder2 = Path to other keystore
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ConfigurationProperties` as below,

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="props.a")
public class A implements ConfigInterface {
  private ... value1;
  private ... value2;
  //getters setters
}

@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="props.b")
public class B implements ConfigInterface {
  private ... value1;
  private ... value2;
  //getters setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On class ***A*** you can use ***@PropertySource("classpath:file1.properties")*** and on class ***B*** you can use ***@PropertySource("classpath:file2.properties")*** annotation. This might help you.

Also, Try using @Configuration annotation also along with @PropertySource if not used already.

Comment: I've tried, but still uses properties from second properties-file

Comment: Will  this actually work? The API docs not `@PropertySource` should be used in conjunction with `@Configuration` classes. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: Yes, it need to be used along with @Configuration

Comment: So essentially it won't work then given A and B are components and not config classes.

Comment: Is it possible to give the @Configuration a qualifier for identification?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to use different properties names. Failing that I believe you would need to remove the `@Component` annotations for A and B and use the alternative mechanism of initializing the beans via `@Configuration` classes as below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("propsA")
public class ConfigurationA{

    @Bean
    public ClassA classA(){
        return new ClassA();
    }
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("propsB")
public class ConfigurationB{

    @Bean
    public ClassB classB(){
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```